# Is the metric ${d(x,y)}\over {1+d(x,y)}$ complete where $d$ is the usual Euclidean metric on $\mathbb R^{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $d(x,y)$  be  the  usual  Euclidean  metric  on   $\mathbb R^{2}.$  $\mathbb R^{2}$ is  complete  under  $d(x,y)$.  I  have  this  subspace  given  $$[0,1]\times [0,\infty )\ \   of\ \   \mathbb R^{2}.$$
 I  thought  this  is   also  complete  under $d$  for  I  could  not  think  of  any  sequence  that is  not  convergent  in  this  space. Correct  me  if  I  am  wrong. Now  the  metric  $$d'(x,y)={{d(x,y)}\over {1+d(x,y)}}$$ on  the  subspace $[0,1]\times [0,\infty )$.  Is  this  complete $?$

I  was  thinking  if  I  could  prove that $d'(x,y)$  and  $d(x,y)$  are  equivalent  then  completeness  would  be  readily  proved. Am  I  thinking  right $?$ 
Need  help  to  further  the  proof.

Thanks  for  any  help.

Comment: You have $d'=\dfrac1{1+\frac1d}=1-\dfrac1{1+d}$, not sure if that helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $d'(x,y)\leq d(x,y)$ for any $x,y$ in your space,
and $d(x,y)\leq 2d'(x,y)$ if $d(x,y)\leq 1$, so a sequence is Cauchy with respect to one metric if and only if it is Cauchy in the other metric.

Comment: Thanks. Another thing  here. For  the  space $[0,1]\times [0,\infty )$  I   did  not  find  counter  example  but  how  to  prove  for  sure  that  this  space  is  complete  under  $d$.

Comment: Well, as you said $\mathbb R^2$ is complete under $d$, and any Cauchy sequence in the subspace $[0,1]\times [0,\infty)$ (under $d$) is also Cauchy as a sequence in $\mathbb R^2$, so has a limit in $\mathbb R^2$. The last thing you need is that $[0,1]\times [0,\infty)$ is a closed subspace of $\mathbb R^2$, so any limit point of a sequence of points in the subspace lies in the subspace.

Comment: Equivalence of metrics means that they generate the same topology. Completeness of a metric does not automatically imply completeness of an equivalent one. For example on the open interval $(0,\pi /2)$  let  $d(x,y)= |x-y|$ and  $e(x,y)=| \tan x - \tan y|$.